# Expression pattern cannot match

Tags: swift, enums

I've been following [this guide](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/writing-network-layer-in-swift-protocol-oriented-approach-4fa40ef1f908) to implement a network layer for my IOS app since it's my first time ever writing an IOS app. I've stumbled upon an error which I don't know what it means or what to do about it:

```swift
public enum GamesApi {
    // how to add getGames()?
    case createGame(game: Game)
    case updateGame(game: Game)
    case deleteGame(id: String)
}

extension GamesApi: EndPointType {

    ...

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .createGame(game: Game): // Expression pattern of type 'Game.Type' cannot match values of type 'Game'
            return "createGame"
        case .updateGame(game: Game): // Expression pattern of type 'Game.Type' cannot match values of type 'Game'
            return "updateGame"
        case .deleteGame(id: String): // Expression pattern of type 'String.Type' cannot match values of type 'String'
            return "deleteGame"
        }
    }

    var httpMethod: HTTPMethod {
        switch self {
        case .createGame(game: Game): // Expression pattern of type 'Game.Type' cannot match values of type 'Game'
            return .post
        case .updateGame(game: Game): // Expression pattern of type 'Game.Type' cannot match values of type 'Game'
            return .put
        case .deleteGame(id: String): // Expression pattern of type 'String.Type' cannot match values of type 'String'
            return .delete
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: `case let .createGame(game: Game)`

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks that did the trick but what does it mean when I put let in front of an enum type? (if you write this out as an answer, I can accept it!)

Comment: You can read about enumeration associated values https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, if I change the `game: Game` to `game: _`, it works as well since I'm not using the game at that moment, it's just part of the syntax